# Adding a class to an element on window resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, window-resize

Depending on the user's screen width, if the image is less than 220px, I want the class of `mobile` to be added to the h3. It works fine by itself but I also want it to work well with window resizing. So if I resize my browser window, it would automatically add the class if the image width becomes less than 220px. I wrote this code below but I can't figure out what is wrong. When I resize the window, the class does not get added. When I refresh, the class is added, however.

```
var thumbWidth = $('article.project > img').outerWidth();
function adjustTitle() {
    if (thumbWidth <= 220) {
        $('.overlay > h3').addClass('mobile');
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    adjustTitle();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the width of the `img` *inside* the `adjustTitle()` function so that it is read *after* the window is resized. Your current code only reads it on load, so the value is never seen to change in your JS. Try this:

```
function adjustTitle() {
    if ($('article.project > img').outerWidth() <= 220) {
        $('.overlay > h3').addClass('mobile');
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', adjustTitle);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really bugging me. Can't believe I didn't think of that after playing around with it so much. I'll accept your answer when I can.